# Ruby Rails - How can I assign a new value to an attribute via link_to?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to, update-attribute

I have a model called projects, and it has an attribute, :opstatus, which I would like to set to 3 (opstatus is an int). I need this to happen when the user clicks the following link:

```
<%= link_to 'Close', projects_path, :action => :newmeth %>
```

For which I created the method (in the projects_controller):

```
def newmeth
    @project.update_attribute(:opstatus, 3)
end
```

But when the user clicks the link, nothing happens!
The database tells me that opstatus still =s 3, and there is no error message.

Can anyone give me a clue as to what I have done wrong?
Thanks!

**Below is the entire contents of my routes.rb file**

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
get 'sheetread/show'
get 'sheetread' => 'sheetread#show'

get 'users/index'

get 'users/new'
get 'welcome/index'
get 'signup' => 'users#new'

get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

resources :users
resources :spreadsheets


resources :projects do
    resources :comments
end

root 'welcome#index'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Add the `newmeth` action to your routes file:

```
resources :projects do
  get :newmeth
  resources :comments
end
```

Also, I strongly suggest you read the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

---

Instead of

```
<%= link_to 'Close', projects_path, :action => :newmeth %>
```

Try

```
<%= link_to 'Close', newmeth_projects_path %>
```

It may not work depending on how you setup your routes, can you paste the relevant lines in your question?

Comment: Okay I see what you mean, I need to set up a route, but is it not possible to simply change the value of opstatus directly from the page, without even invoking a method? I tried link_to body, url, :'opstatus'=> 3 but no luck..

Comment: No, you can't. You need to pass through the controller. And you need to set up the route.